# How to prevent a duplicate entry on name on SugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm

I have created a custom module and I wanted to prevent users from entering the same name twice and if they do then forcefully stop them from saving record. I've changed its display label: "BL No.." Now i want users to enter unique value for every record name field.

Comment: you need to mention sugar version as well.

Comment: Im sorry. Im using Sugar Version 6.5.25 (Build 344).

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate Check logic can be added/modified for a module in the vardef.  The following is an example for Contacts:

```
'duplicate_check' => array(
    'enabled' => true,
    'FilterDuplicateCheck' => array(
        'filter_template' => array(
            array(
                '$and' => array(
                    array('first_name' => array('$starts' => '$first_name')),
                    array('last_name' => array('$starts' => '$last_name')),
                    array('accounts.id' => array('$equals' => '$account_id')),
                    array('dnb_principal_id' => array('$equals' => '$dnb_principal_id')),
                )
            ),
        ),
        'ranking_fields' => array(
        ),
    ),
)
```

The logic is based on the FilterApi syntax. For convert lead, the option to turn on/off duplicate check needs to be implemented through modifying the convert-main.php.  For your custom module, you can modify the following attribute:

```
'duplicateCheckOnStart' => true,
```

to decide whether duplicate check runs when you start the lead conversion process.